# Is $\mathsf{R}$ axiomatizable by finitely many schemes?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, proof-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

Recall that $\mathsf{R}$ is the theory of arithmetic consisting of the quantifier-free theory of $(\mathbb{N};+,\times,0,1,<)$ together with, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the sentence $$\forall x[(\bigwedge_{i\le k}x\not=\underline{i})\rightarrow \underline{k}<x]$$ where $\underline{n}$ is the numeral standing for $n$. $\mathsf{R}$ is strong enough to be subject to the first incompleteness theorem *(see [Beklemishev](http://www.mi-ras.ru/%7Ebekl/Papers/goedel-en.pdf) and [Jerabek](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09864) for some relevant information on this point)* and is not finitely axiomatizable (in contrast with Robinson's more famous arithmetic $\mathsf{Q}$).

My question is **whether $\mathsf{R}$ is finitely axiomatizable when we allow *schemes*, in a limited sense, as well as sentences**. By "scheme" here I mean the following:

> A **scheme of sentences** in a given language $\Sigma$ is a sentence $\sigma$ in the language gotten by adding a new relation symbol $A$ (of some finite arity) to $\Sigma$. An **instance** of a scheme $\sigma$ is then a sentence of the form $$\forall y_1,...,y_n(\sigma[A/\varphi(y_1,...,y_n,x_1,....,x_k)])$$ where $\varphi$ is some $(n+k)$-ary formula in the original language $\Sigma$ and $\sigma[A/\varphi(y_1,...,y_n,x_1,..., x_k)]$ is the $L$-formula gotten by replacing each "$A(t_1,...,t_k)$" with "$\varphi(y_1,...,y_n,t_1,...,t_k)$" throughout $\sigma$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3594021/28111) for some comments on this notion. A theory is scheme-finitely axiomatizable if it can be axiomatized by a finite set of sentences together with the set of all instances of finitely many schemes in the above sense. Clearly every scheme-finitely axiomatizable theory is computably axiomatizable, but [the converse fails](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363581/8133) even for finite languages. I suspect that in fact $\mathsf{R}$ witnesses the failure of the converse - basically, $\mathsf{R}$ doesn't seem to entail any nontrivial schemes in this particular sense at all - but I don't see how to prove that. Separately, I don't believe that the [Visser/Vaught result on axiomatization by schemes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41575876?seq=1) can give a *positive* answer here, since $\mathsf{R}$ seems to lack the needed coding power.

Comment: And, indeed, R cannot interpret $\mathrm{VS}_2$ at all (let alone directly), as $\mathrm{VS}_2$ is a finite theory with no finite models, while R is locally finitely satisfiable.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Fascinating, I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: Harvey Friedman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ne7V_9RTeTc recently raised the same question. What I figured out after a bit of thinking about that is that there is a locally finitely satisfiable theory axiomatized by finitely many schemes that doesn't have a finite model. Namely, the theory of discrete linear orders with the scheme $\exists x \exists y( x<y \land \forall z (x\le z \land z\le y \to (F(x)\leftrightarrow F(z)))$ (for any definable set $A$ either $A$ or its complement contains an interval of the size $\ge 2$). The trick here is to use $o$-minimality of discrete linear orders.

Comment: Also I know how under a certain plausible complexity-theoretic assumption (a strengthening of $\mathtt{PH}\ne\mathtt{PSPACE}$) to construct a locally finitely satisfiable extension of $\mathsf{R}$ axiomatized by finitely many schemes. Note that by a result of Visser https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.152.7121&rep=rep1&type=pdf theory $\mathsf{R}$ is the interpretability-greatest locally finitely satisfiable theory. Hence this extension of $\mathsf{R}$ will be mutually interpretable with $\mathsf{R}$.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov While that doesn't fully answer the question, it does make significant progress - could you add it as an answer so I can award it the bounty?

Answer (score 4):

This answer is merely an advancement on the original question rather than a full answer.

Recall that a theory is locally finitely satisfiable if all its finite subtheories have finite models. Below I sketch a proof of the following theorem.

**Theorem.** There exists an extension $\mathsf{U}$ of $\mathsf{R}$ that is axiomatized by finitely many schemes such that the assumption $\mathtt{PH}\ne\mathtt{ExpTime}$ implies that $\mathsf{U}$ is locally finitely satisfiable.

Note that there is a result of Visser [1] that $\mathsf{R}$ interprets any locally finitely satisfiable theory. Thus the theorem above implies that if $\mathtt{PH}\ne\mathtt{ExpTime}$, then there is a locally finitely satisfiable theory that is mutually interpretable with $\mathsf{R}$.

**Proof.** Let us fix a theory $\mathsf{U}_0$ axiomatized by finitely many schemes such that all its infinite models are models of $\mathsf{R}$ and its finite models are precisely the rings $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ (the order in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ is the standard order on the set $\{0,1,\ldots,2^n-1\}$).

We identify elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ with the binary strings of the length $n$, where each number corresponds to its own binary expansion. For formulas $\varphi(x)$ we consider the languages $$D_\varphi=\{\alpha\mid \mathbb{Z}_{2^{|\alpha|}}\models\varphi(\alpha)\}.$$ If $\varphi(x)$ is a first-order arithmetical formula, then clearly $D_\varphi\in\texttt{PH}$. Observe that
$$\{D_\varphi\mid \varphi(x)\in \Sigma^1_1\}=\bigcup_{k\in\omega} \mathtt{NTime}(2^{xk}),$$
where in $\Sigma^1_1$-formulas we allow quantification over predicates of any finite arity.

Fix an $\mathtt{ExpTime}$-complete language $L$ such that $L\in \mathtt{Time}(2^{xk})$, for some $k$. Clearly, $L,\bar{L}\in \mathtt{NTime}(2^{xk'})$, for   some $k'$. Fix $\Sigma^1_1$-formulas $\varphi_0(x)$ and $\varphi_1(x)$ such that $S_{\varphi_0}=L$ and $S_{\varphi_0}=\bar L$. For $i\in\{0,1\}$ the formula $\varphi_i(x)$ is of the form $\exists X^{(n_i)} \psi_i(x,X^{(n_i)})$. Let $U$ be the extension of $U_0$ by the scheme $$\exists x (\lnot \psi_0(x,X^{(n_0+1)}\upharpoonright x)\land \lnot \psi_1(x,Y^{(n_1+1)}\upharpoonright x)),$$
where $X^{(n+1)}\upharpoonright x$ is the $n$-ary relation $\{(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\mid (x,y_1,\ldots,y_n)\in X^{(n+1)}\}$.

Observe that $U$ doesn't have finite models. Indeed any model $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ clearly satisfies the $\Sigma^1_1$-sentence corresponding to the negation of the scheme above: $$\exists X^{(n_0+1)}, Y^{(n_1+1)}\forall x ( \psi_0(x,X^{(n_0+1)}\upharpoonright x)\lor \psi_1(x,Y^{(n_1+1)}\upharpoonright x)).$$ Thus for any $n$ we could construct an instance of the scheme that would fail in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$.

To finish the proof we use the assumption $\mathtt{PH}\ne \mathtt{ExpTime}$ to show that any finite fragment of $U$ has a finite model. Otherwise there would be $N$ and fisrt-order formulas $\theta_{i,j}(x,y_1,\ldots,y_{n_j},\vec{p}_i)$, $0\le i<N$, and $j\in\{0,1\}$ such that
$$\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}\models \bigvee\limits_{0\le i<N}\exists \vec{p}_i\forall x (\bigvee_{j\in\{0,1\}} \psi_j(x,\{(y_1,\ldots,y_{n_j})\mid \theta_{i,j}(x,y_1,\ldots,y_{n_j})\})).$$
But in fact this implies that $L$ is equal to $D_\eta$, where $\eta(x)$ is
$$\bigvee\limits_{0\le i<N}\exists \vec{p}_i(\psi_0(x,\{(y_1,\ldots,y_{n_0})\mid \theta_{i,0}(x,y_1,\ldots,y_{n_0})\})).$$
Thus $L\in\mathtt{PH}$, contradicting the assumption that $\mathtt{PH}\ne\mathtt{ExpTime}$. **QED**

[1] Visser, A. "Why the theory R is special." Logic Group preprint series 279 (2009).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, sure.

Comment: Why is $U_0$ axiomatizable by finitely many axiom schemata?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Of course I meant that we should fix $\mathsf{U}_0$ axiomatized by finitely many schemes (I have edited the answer to clarify this). I have in mind the following axiomatization of $\mathsf{U}_0$: 1. < is a linear order, where 0 is the least element and there is the greatest element $m$; 2. $0+1=1$; 3. $m+1=0$; 4. $x<x+1$ and $(x,x+1)=\emptyset$, for $0\le x <m$; 5.  $x+0=x$; 6. $x+(y+1)=(x+y)+1$; 7. $x0=0$; 8. $x(y+1)=xy+x$; 9. either $0=m$ or there is $u<m$ s.t. $(u+1)+u=m$ and for any $0<x<u+1$ and $1<p<u+1$ if $xp=u+1$ and $p$ isn't $zw$ for any $1<z,w<p$, then $p=1+1$.

Comment: Oh I see; it didn’t occur to me that one can force the universe to be a power of $2$ with finitely many axioms like this. Presumably you want $1<p\le u+1$ rather than $1<p<u+1$, as otherwise the axioms also hold in $\mathbb Z_{2p}$ for odd primes $p$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, indeed it should have been $1<p\le u+1$, thank you.